# Running MIPS instructions on a real machine [not on simulator]

Tags: mips, emulation

I'm working on MIPS in college and we are using *Qtspim* simulator for running *MIPS* instructions. I've googled on how to run *MIPS* code on my real machine (**not** any simulator like SPIM) but I couldn't find any comment. Is it possible to create an executable file from *MIPS* instructions?

On another lecture of mine (System Programming) we have been using *MASM615* for compiling assembly instructions by using `make32` command from the cmd. I'm looking for any similar tool. Are there any exist for MIPS?

Comment: If you want to run MIPS machine code, you'll need a MIPS CPU, which your computer probably doesn't have. Are you looking for a compiler that compiles MIPS assembly language into x86 machine code? I'm not sure that would have any advantage over simulation.

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/ mpx_samples and pic32_samples are both mips based, show how to build mips executables from source code and for each system run them.  the mpx is an opencores core that you can simulate on the pic32 is hardware you have to buy.  Once you have a binary you need a mips processor to run it which is the reason for a simulator or buying mips hardware.  some sony playstation hardware is mips based so you can use one of those simulators or hardware if you can hack them.  the gcw-zero coming out soon is also mips based (and many other platforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an executable file from MIPS instructions?

Yes, because an assembler is just a program that reads some input and produce some output files, therefore you can assemble for any architectures from any other architectures, in the same way as the possibility to [cross-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Compiler) for other architectures from your PC

But executing the output file is an entirely different thing. Each architecture has its own machine language. Just like how humans can't understand people speaking other languages, machines only understand programs written in its language. That means MIPS hardware can only understand and run MIPS binaries. Other architectures like x86 can't interpret another instruction set with different instruction coding

So the only way for you is to use an [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) or [simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation)

See also

- [How can I execute MIPS assembly programs on an x86 linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/464313/995714)
- [How to run a MIPS binary on x86 platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43563286/995714)
- [How to run i386 binary on MIPS platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27543870/995714)