# How to run i386 binary on MIPS platform?

Tags: mips, emulation, executable, i386

I have an i386 binary that I would like to run on my STB with embedded linux.

How to run the i386 binary (compiled on Ubuntu / compiler : i486-linux-gnu-libusb) on MIPS arch platform (set-top box)?

Comment: Could you tell what you have tried till now ?

Comment: You can't without some form of emulation (i.e. using QEmu), but I don't believe any x86 emulation platforms exist for MIPS. Even then, emulating x86 on MIPS will yield absolutely *terrible* performance. If you have the source, cross-compile it to the MIPS target instead.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll recompile it with mips toolchain. I can't lose performance on STB

Answer (score 0):

You need an [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator). The most well-known emulators are [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) and [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) which are both open-source

However emulation is slow by nature, so it's only used for non-performance-critical applications that no source code is available. Real-time software like decoders in a set-top-box definitely isn't suitable to execute under emulation. You need to rebuild the software to MIPS target

See also

- [How to run a MIPS binary on x86 platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43563286/995714)
- [How can I execute MIPS assembly programs on an x86 linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/464313/995714)