# How to run a MIPS binary on x86 platform?

Tags: linux, x86, 64-bit, mips, emulation

Is there any way to run a MIPS binary on a Linux x86/x86-x64 machine? I got some applications for Enigma2 set-top-boxes (which is also based on Linux) that I want to run on a x86/x86-64 machine. These plugins are only available for MIPS processors.

Comment: You need to find MIPS emulators for Linux and run your apps inside emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute MIPS assembly programs on an x86 linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464313/how-can-i-execute-mips-assembly-programs-on-an-x86-linux)

Comment: @phuclv that question refers to the spim emulator which can only emulate assembly but not the binary itself

Answer (score 3):

The keyword is ["emulator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator). The most famous emulator is [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) which can pretty much emulate any architectures out there, but there are also lots of MIPS emulators on Linux that you can find in the [Linux-MIPS wiki](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Emulators):

> 1. Open Virtual Platforms (OVP) OVPsim
> 2. GXemul
> 3. SimOS
> 4. Sulima
> 5. MIPSsim
> 6. MipsSim
> 7. SPIM
> 8. VMIPS
> 9. Virtutech Simics
> 10. SandUPSim
> 11. MPS
> 12. YAMS
> 13. MAME/MESS
> 14. MISSE
> 15. Cisco 7200 Simulator
> 16. QEMU
> 17. VirtualMIPS
> 18. Miep
> 19. MARS
> 20. QtMips

Note that there are full-system emulation (which is heavier) and user-mode emulation which emulates a single process. Depending on which type you need you must choose one, but qemu supports both

> - Full-system emulation: Run operating systems for any machine, on any supported architecture
> - User-mode emulation: Run programs for another Linux/BSD target, on any supported architecture

However performance will be terrible so you'll never want to run an app that need to be fast like a video decoder in a set-top-box. If the source is available then just recompile it

See [Decompile / Run MIPS executable under x86_64 Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179593/44425)

Comment: Some of these emulate a whole machine that you can run Linux-MIPS on (e.g. QEMU).  Others emulate a "toy" MIPS with some "system calls" that call into the emulator itself as a simple standard library for reading/writing strings and numbers in various formats, and maybe some MMIO devices or video RAM (MARS, SPIM).  Important to sort your list into different types of emulators.

Comment: Also, some are emulators (applying the as-if rule however they want, like dynamic recompilation at least when you're not single-stepping, e.g. maybe QEMU), while others are actual *simulators*, e.g. of the classic 5-stage RISC pipeline.  MARS has a microarchitecture window you can open to see instructions go through pipeline stages.

Answer (score 0):

Qemu could be your Messiah this time. I use it personally and it really saves a lot of pain using an FPGA. 
https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/QEMU

Of course, this isn't natively executing the MIPS binary on your computer. But I suppose that if you can find plugin of your app coded for MIPS processors, the app itself can be found for MIPS.